# I have been working on a project and I use like components to import code so the main code stays clean, I got errors and can't seem to fix it

Tags: javascript, html, web, components, ejs

Here is the error

```
[WEBSITE] An error has occured on path /dashboard:
TypeError: ./themes/default/dashboard.ejs:37
    35|         <% } %>
    36|         <%- include('./components/ads') %>
 >> 37|         <%- include('./components/status') %>
    38|             <div class="row ">
    39|               <div class="col-12 grid-margin">
    40|                 <div class="card">

/home/container/themes/default/components/status.ejs:20
    18|               <h6> class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">CPU</h5>
    19|               <div class="d-flex align-items-center align-self-start">
 >> 20|                 <h3> class="mb-0"><%= cpu %> / <%= packages.cpu + extraresources.cpu + join4res.cpu %>%</h3>
    21|               </div>
    22|             </div>
    23|           </div>

Cannot read property 'cpu' of undefined
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/container/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:26:35)
    at status (/home/container/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
    at include (/home/container/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:690:39)
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/container/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:59:17)
    at dashboard (/home/container/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/container/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/container/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at /home/container/index.js:255:7 {
  path: './themes/default/dashboard.ejs'
}
```

And here is `components/status.ejs` file

```
<div class="row">
    <%
      let ram = 0;
      let disk = 0;
      let cpu = 0;
      let servers = pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data.length;
      for (let i = 0, len = pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data.length; i < len; i++) {
          ram = ram + (typeof pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.limits.memory == "number" ? pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.limits.memory : 0);
          disk = disk + (typeof pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.limits.disk == "number" ? pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.limits.disk : 0);
          cpu = cpu + (typeof pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.limits.cpu == "number" ? pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.limits.cpu : 0);
      }
    %>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9">
              <h6> class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">CPU</h5>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center align-self-start">
                <h3> class="mb-0"><%= cpu %> / <%= packages.cpu + extraresources.cpu + join4res.cpu %>%</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9">
              <h6 class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">RAM</h5>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center align-self-start">
                <h3 class="mb-0"><%= ram %> / <%= packages.ram + extraresources.ram + join4res.ram %>MB</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9">
              <h6 class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">DISK</h5>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center align-self-start">
                <h3 class="mb-0"><%= disk %> / <%= packages.disk + extraresources.disk + join4res.disk %>MB</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9">
              <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">SERVERS</h5>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center align-self-start">
                <h3 class="mb-0"><%= servers %> / <%= packages.servers + extraresources.servers + join4res.servers %></h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is `dashboard.ejs` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <%- include('./components/head') %>
  <body>
    <div class="container-scroller">
      <!-- partial:partials/_sidebar.html -->
      <%- include('./components/sidebar') %>
      <!-- partial -->
      <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
        <!-- partial:partials/_navbar.html -->
        <%- include('./components/topnav') %>
        <!-- partial -->
        <div class="main-panel">
          <div class="content-wrapper">

            <%- include('./components/alert') %>
            <% if (req.query.err == "ALREADY_OPEN") { %>
                <div class="alert">
                    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                    You can't open multiple tabs!
                </div>
            <% } %>
            <% if (req.session.newaccount || req.session.password) { %>
            <div class="alert">
                <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                <% if (req.session.newaccount) { %>
                    Heliactyl successfully created a new account for you.<br>
                <% } %>
                <% if (req.session.password) { %>
                    Your <% if (!req.session.newaccount) { %>new <% } %>password is <%= req.session.password %>! Make sure to keep this password in a safe place.
                <% } else { %>
                    Please head over to Settings to create a password.
                <% } %>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <%- include('./components/ads') %>
        <%- include('./components/status') %>
            <div class="row ">
              <div class="col-12 grid-margin">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Your Servers</h4>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th> Server Name </th>
                            <th> CPU </th>
                            <th> RAM </th>
                            <th> Disk </th>
                            <th> Options </th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <% if (pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data.length == 0) { %>
                              <tr>
                              <td> No servers found. </td>
                              </tr>
                            <% } else { %>
                              <% for (let i = 0, len = pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data.length; i < len; i++) { %>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <span class="pl-2"><%= pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.name.length > 40 ? pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.name.slice(0, 40) + "..." : pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.name %></span>
                                </td>
                                <td> <%= pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.limits.cpu %>% </td>
                                <td> <%= pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.limits.memory %>MB </td>
                                <td> <%= pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.limits.disk %>MB </td>
                                <td>
                                <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/servers/edit?id=<%= pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.id %>">Edit</a>
                                <a role="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="if (confirm('Please confirm you want to delete this server, the data cannot be retrieved after it has been deleted.')) { window.location.href='/delete?id=<%= pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.id %>' }">Delete</a>
                                <% if (settings.api.client.allow.renewsuspendsystem.enabled) { %>
                                <a role="button" class="btn btn-info" href="/renew?id=<%= pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.id %>">Renew</a>
                                <% } %>
                                <a role="button" class="btn btn-warning" href="<%= settings.pterodactyl.domain %>/server/<%= pterodactyl.relationships.servers.data[i].attributes.identifier %>">Link</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                              <% } %>
                            <% } %>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
          <%- include('./components/footer') %>
        </div>
        <!-- main-panel ends -->
      </div>
      <!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- container-scroller -->
    <%- include('./components/scripts') %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! (This is a client page for a open source project called Pterodactyl btw) It uses pterodactyl api to allow users to create, manage and delete servers... Its self hosted on pterodactyl itself. The pterodactyl project can be found at https://pterodactyl.io incase you need a reference or so to answer this particular thread.

Comment: Also as soon as i tell the `dashboard.ejs` not to import `/components/status.ejs` it does not give out any errors.